# PyCharm Terminal does not print any output

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm completely new to Python and have downloaded the PyCharm IDE. I made a first little program that simply prints the given arguments:

```
import sys

print("Start")
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
print("End")
```

Now I am trying to execute this program and pass arguments through the IDE. I have found the Run Configurations editor, but I don't want to set some fixed arguments on every launch, I want to play around and call the script with different arguments.

I then saw the "Terminal" in PyCharm, and thought I can call the script from there passing the arguments. However when I do that, I just get nothing. It doesn't print anything in Terminal. It only prints in the "Run" Tab, but also doesn't seem to take my passed arguments.

Somewhere on the internet I found someone suggesting to enable "Emulate Terminal in output console" in the Run Configurations. I did that but nothing changed.

So my question in short: What do I have to do in PyCharm to be able to quickly call a program with arguments and get output from the program directly within the Terminal/Shell/whatever-it-might-be where I ran the program from? I can't imagine that you would have to go through the Run Configurations everytime you want to call a script and pass something new.

Thanks!

Comment: You can call the script from the terminal tab, just as you would with the actual terminal. It shouldn't print anything in the "Run" tab, so it suggests you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out why it didn't work. I just ran the script entering the script's name, i.e.:

```
test.py
```

however it needs to be run as:

```
python test.py
```

The reason I didn't realize this earlier is that running just test.py doesn't give any error like "unknown command" or so. Not even on windows cmd. So I'm not quite sure what the computer is doing when executing the script just with name. Anyways, running it with python program explicitly works now, also in PyCharm Terminal.